# Firebase functions logger log is undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

functions.logger.log("Hello from info. Here's an object:", someObj);
```

So when I run functions.logger.log this is the error I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'log' of undefined

Why is logger undefined and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your version of the firebase-functions module.  The logger requires [version 3.7.0](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v3.7.0) or later.  The latest at the time of this writing is 3.13.0.